# Integral of a power function of a CDF

Tags: integration, order-statistics

Is there a general formula to compute the integral $\int_0^s(F(x))^Ndx$ without knowing the exact expression of $F(x)$ but knowing that it is a CDF?

What about $\int_0^sF(x)[1-F(x)]dx?$

Comment: doubt it. $F$ could be any nondecreasing function $\mathbb R \to [0, 1]$ with $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = 1$, and $F$ is right continuous. The point being... this is an incredibly weak constraint on $F$ to expect a general formula for its integral.